# Creating package extension to other package [Python]

Tags: python, import, package

Dears,

I would like to create a Python package that can be extended with other pip-installable packages, that extends the first core package with new features.

The issue I have it to import these "extensions" subpackage in the core library namespace/path.
Let me explain it better with an example:

The core library is setup like this:

```
library/
    setup.py
    library/
        __init.py__
        core/
            core_module1.py
            core_module2.py
```

Then, I have developed a new package called

```
library-feature/
    setup.py
    library_feature/
        __init__.py
        feature/
            __init__.py
            feature_module1.py
            feature_module2.py
```

How can I use the feature modules with importing just the core library?

```
import library

from library.core.core_module1 import core_function
from library.feature.feature_module1 import feature_function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting these lines of code into `library/__init__.py`

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

And renaming the subpackage
`feature-library/feature_library`
into
`feature-library/library`

So that we can access the `feature` functionalities from the `library` namespace.

For more info follow [this link to the official documentation](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/)